# Working With Rate Limits on GitHub's GraphQL API

Tags: github, graphql, github-api, github-graphql

I understand that GitHub's GraphQL API [has a rate limit](https://developer.github.com/v4/guides/resource-limitations/), which requires you to use slicing with `first`, `last`, `before`, `after`, etc. However, what if I just want a count of a particular field? For example, I don't want to get all of a user's followers, I just want to get the follower count. Here's the query:

```
query {
    user(login: "parkerziegler") {
      login,
      name,
      avatarUrl(size: 200)
      bio,
      company,
      location,
      createdAt,
      followers {
        // what can I do here to get the count rather than info on followers?
      }
    }
}
```

In general, **I'm interested in how to deal with these types of calculations in GraphQL, i.e. SUM or ORDER BY**. I'm guessing these need to be implemented on the server, but just curious if anyone has any insights. I've been reading a bit about [pagination](http://graphql.org/learn/pagination/) but don't know if it's the solution for my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get follower count using `totalCount` under `followers` :

```graphql
{
  user(login: "parkerziegler") {
    login
    name
    avatarUrl(size: 200)
    bio
    company
    location
    createdAt
    followers {
      totalCount
    }
  }
}
```

[Try it in the explorer](https://developer.github.com/v4/explorer/?query=%7B%0A%20%20user(login%3A%20%22parkerziegler%22)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20login%0A%20%20%20%20name%0A%20%20%20%20avatarUrl(size%3A%20200)%0A%20%20%20%20bio%0A%20%20%20%20company%0A%20%20%20%20location%0A%20%20%20%20createdAt%0A%20%20%20%20followers%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20totalCount%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A)

You can check [FollowerConnection](https://developer.github.com/v4/object/followerconnection/#followerconnection) object